# Add validations to Django model

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework for an app. Below is the **Feature model** :

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    image_component = models.ForeignKey('Image_Component',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    feature_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20 )
    feature_value = models.CharField(max_length = 30)


    def save(self , *args , **kwargs):
        if not self.feature_type in ['size','quality','format']:
            raise Exception("Incorrect")
        else:
            super(Feature, self).save(*args , **kwargs)

    def validate(self , data):
        if data['feature_type'] == 'size':
            print self.feature_value.is_alnum()
            if not data['feature_value'].is_alnum():
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect value')
        return data
```

The serializer class for feature model is :

```
class FeatureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Feature
        field = ('id','feature_value')
```

Below is the corresponding view :

```
class Feature(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Feature.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FeatureSerializer
```

I want to validate the model such that if any user is inputing the value for **feature_value** as *size* then he/she can input it only in the form of "200x200"(if not this then alphanumeric). I tried to do this in the validate function in Feature model but its not working.Can someone tell me how to rectify this error.

Also the print statement in the validate method doesn't print anything which means the validate method is not at all called as said in the doc.

Comment: use `clean` instead of `validate`, for `feature_value` field validation, corresponding method should be `def clean_feature_value(self):`

Comment: @AvinashRaj still not working

Comment: show your current attempt.

Comment: def clean_feature_value(self):
        if self.feature_type == 'size':
            print self.feature_value.is_alnum()
            if not self.feature_value.is_alnum():
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect value')

Comment: `if self.cleaned_data['feature_type'] == 'size':`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104236/discussion-between-the-flash-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 0):

Code not tested. Using argument **validators** in CharField method

```
def validate_feature_type(self , data):
        if data['feature_type'] == 'size':
            print self.feature_value.is_alnum()
            if not data['feature_value'].is_alnum():
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect value')

class Feature(models.Model):
    image_component = models.ForeignKey('Image_Component', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    feature_type = models.CharField(max_length = 2, validators=[validate_feature_type] )
    feature_value = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```